# Select an element by id from other archive

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get an element by id from other archive in my project

Some stuff like this:

```
const elements = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('arquivo1/#item1, arquivo2/#item2' )
     );
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `id` should be unique and therefore does not require a preselector. What is an archive?

Comment: I mean with archive "another html document"

Comment: `arquivo1.getElementById('item1')`, `arquivo2.getElementById('item2')`

Comment: So you mean `arquivo2` is your second html file and you want to get an element by id `item2` in `arquivo.html` file?